# How to bridge Objective-C++ code to Swift when we have C++ classes as parameters in header files?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to call C++ methods from Swift, and what I've learnt is that I can wrap the C++ stuff to an Objective-C++ class first, then export this Objective-C++ class to Swift. Here's my code:

```
// CPPClass.h
class CPPClass {
    int data;
};


// OCClass.h
#import "CPPClass.h"
@interface OCClass : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithCPPObject:(CPPClass &)obj;

@end


// MyProject-Bridging-Header.h
#import "OCClass.h"
```

When I build the project, the compiler throws an **Expected a type** error in `OCClass.h`. If I comment out the header file in `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h`, everything becomes fine, except that I can't use it in Swift any more.

I can solve it by replacing the specific C++ type parameter with a `void *` pointer, and in this case I can freely use `CPPClass` in `OCClass.mm` file, but I wonder if there's any more elegant solutions?

Comment: You've misread something. You can expose your C++ stuff as **Objective-C**, not Objective-C++. It needs to have a pure ObjC interface. It cannot expose C++ in the header (although the implementation may be in ObjC++). For some old discussion on this, see https://robnapier.net/wrapping-c-take-2-1